# Youtube's autoplay video is not wroking on flutter webview for Android

Tags: flutter, android-webview, flutter-web, youtube-iframe-api, autoplay

I am Using Flutter's `Webview` for loading my **youtube url** and what I want is to autoplay that video once webview loads. 
I am using an `.html file` placed in my `assets` folder for loading the url from a local asset file.

Below is my code for the same-

**my_asset.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    body,html{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <iframe width ="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uJCzdk4EFgw?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And my **webview.dart** file -

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: null,
      body:SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: WebView(
                initialUrl:"about:blank",
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  _controller = webViewController;
                  _loadHtmlFromAssets();
                },
                ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 10.0,
              right: 10.0,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Image.asset(AppAssets.closeIcon),
                iconSize: 30.0,
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ),


          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

    return Container();
  }

  _loadHtmlFromAssets() async {
    String fileText = await rootBundle.loadString(widget.asset);
    _controller.loadUrl( Uri.dataFromString(
        fileText,
        mimeType: 'text/html',
        encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8')
    ).toString());
  }
```

the key to AutoPlay is **?autoplay=1** but it is not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter official Webview has many problems, some times this library in some js functions doesn't work and crashes the application. And this library still **development preview**. But [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) library is very useful and working very stable. Btw: I use flutter_webview_plugin, I switched from official library to flutter_webview_plugin